# get total cost for items in cart with php

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have two `sql` tables named `products` and `cart`.
In `products` table containing all of product details.
In `cart` table containing only `userID` and `productID`

I want to show total cost for all items in cart. I tried with this two functions, but I'm getting error.

These are my functions:

```
function totalPrice($user){
    $cost = 0;
    $query = "SELECT item_id FROM cart WHERE user_id='".$user."'";

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    while($itemid = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $iprice = getProductPrice($itemid);
        $cost += $iprice;
    }

    return $cost;
}

function getProductPrice($item_id){
    $query = "SELECT product_price FROM products WHERE product_id='".$item_id."'";

    $result = mysql_result(mysql_query($query), 0);

    return $result;
}
```

When I call `totalPrice($_SESSION['user'])`, I am getting this error

```
Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 23 in C:\xampp\htdocs\s\product\includes\cartprocess.php on line 50

Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 24 in C:\xampp\htdocs\s\product\includes\cartprocess.php on line 50
```

How can I solve this problem with small edit??

Comment: Is the $user variable set?

Comment: is `$item_id` set and are you sure that the second query has any result?

Comment: $user_id is already set.second query has two results

Comment: @Peter : Sorry It's a mistake when I copy the code.

Comment: Don't chain DB calls like that. Never assume a DB call will succeed. If the query the fails, it returns boolean FALSE (not a statement handle) and then the "outer" function will start spewing errors. Always assume failure, check for failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise. And technically, your code is reundant. Why not use a SINGLE `join`ed query so you don't need to run queries in your sub-function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your while loop to:

```
while ($itemid = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $iprice = getProductPrice($itemid);
    $cost += $iprice;
}
```

I would also change your function to:

```
function getProductPrice($item_id){
    $query = "SELECT product_price FROM products WHERE product_id='".$item_id."' LIMIT 1";

    $result = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($query));

    return $result['product_price'];
}
```

Comment: Sorry It's a mistake when I copy the code.code is already like your answer in my real file

Comment: @OP I'm sorry, really messing up. It should be working like this